# simple video capturing in windows from webcam using directshow in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to write a simple program which records a short video from webcam only of few seconds and store it in a file but I am unable to do so. Kindly if anyone has gone through this thing before please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using opencv instead. There are a number of books and opensource projects. Example taken from (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture)

Here is a simple framework to connect to a camera and show the images in a Window.

```
#include "cv.h" 
#include "highgui.h" 
#include <stdio.h>  
// A Simple Camera Capture Framework 
int main() {
  CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
  if ( !capture ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
    getchar();
    return -1;
  }
 // Create a window in which the captured images will be presented
 cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
 while ( 1 ) {
   // Get one frame
   IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
   if ( !frame ) {
     fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
     getchar();
     break;
   }
   cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
   // Do not release the frame!
   //If ESC key pressed, Key=0x10001B under OpenCV 0.9.7(linux version),
   //remove higher bits using AND operator
   if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
 }
 // Release the capture device housekeeping
 cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
 cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to do it without openCV using Directshow API. I want to store the still images as bitmap on disk so that I can convert them to Avi file later on. I have done the Avi part but is unable to capture bmp images from camera